# How can I select a user control by grid row and column number?

Tags: c#, datagrid, user-controls

Is it possible to select a user control based on grid name, grid row and grid column? I would like to toggle a checkbox based on a row number and column number within a grid.

This is what I have :

```
for( i = 1; i<7; i++) 
{ 
  for (j = 1; j < 33; j++) 
  {
    CheckBox a = new CheckBox(); 
    a.Name = "SAT_ID_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
    this.Sat_ID_Grid.Children.Add(a);
    a.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ReadOnlyCheckBox"); 
    Grid.SetRow(a, i ); Grid.SetColumn(a, j );
   }
}
```

Once created, How can I reference the checkboxes if I know the name?

Comment: what have you done so far to achieve this. Please do your part of the work and ask for help when you are struck.

Comment: WPF or WinForms? What type of Grid?

Comment: This is what I have. Sorry I tried my best to format the text into code, doesnt work
 for( i = 1; i<7; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < 33; j++)
            {
                CheckBox a = new CheckBox();
                a.Name = "SAT_ID_" + i.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString();
                this.Sat_ID_Grid.Children.Add(a);
                a.Style = (Style)Application.Current.FindResource("ReadOnlyCheckBox");
                Grid.SetRow(a, i );
                Grid.SetColumn(a, j );
            }
        }
Once created, How can I reference the checkboxes if I know the name? WPF

Answer (score 1):

Use FindControl(), and you don't need to look for Cell.

Something like :

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("Name_of_your_User_Control")
```

Comment: When I tried to reference the ".Rows", it doesnt have that particular property. it is a Grid within the xaml

Comment: @user2584960 did you try using the element in array as `.Rows[0]` or just `.Rows` ? You need acces a row, that in this example will be `.Rows[0]`. `.Rows` will bring the collection of rows, and do not have a `FindControl` method.

Comment: @user2584960 What is the type of your 'grid' ? Is it a GridView ? Also, what kind of project is this? Is it a webform, windows forms, mvc?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done .. try something like this

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = true;
```

Assuming that the column at index 1 is of type `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`

Comment: When I tried to reference the ".Rows", it doesnt have that particular property. it is a Grid within the xaml